# Properties of C# set and get

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I printed it to the console and it wrote me `false`.

```
bool _turnedOn, _turnedOff;

public bool Start { get => _turnedOn; private set => _turnedOn = true; }
```

Why it returns `false` if I set the variable to `true`?

Comment: Why do you have both a turnedOn and a turnedOff bool?

Comment: when you run the application, instance of the application class, MyClass app = new MyClass(); app.Start = false; must be set (or in the constructor). Just defining the set property doesn't initialize the property (and if not set the default value is false for bool types.

Comment: What's the point of having a setter that not only _completely **ignores** the `value`_ but always sets the field `_turnedOn = true`.  Unless your code is directly writing to the field `_turnedOn` elsewhere you may as well make `_turnedOn` a `const` and remove the property.

Comment: Making games early in your career is an exciting prospect (I can totally relate).  Learning C# and .NET is also exciting venture.  However, tackling both C# and Unity at the same time can be akin to fighting a _war on two fronts._  Sometimes it's better to learn the language first, or at least become accustomed prior to leaping into Unity.  Whilst learning C# you could always make a console app game like say **Zork**.  That way you'll have a better foundation and also be ready for the _Unity-way-of-doing-things._  In any event, good luck.  Hoping to see games from you in the future! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
bool _turnedOn, _turnedOff;
```

These are both false. When you access `Start`, it's going to give you `_turnedOn`, which is false. It doesn't get set to true until you try to set `Start` to anything, because you've defined the setter as `_turnedOn = true`.

If you declare it as `bool _turnedOn = true;` then you'll get what you want I think, but I don't understand the point. Why bother with a value that you want to be always true?

Comment: Its for my homework and later i am goig to delete the second variable and use it as false also anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

In .NET (including C#), booleans are set to False by default.

> The default value of the bool type is false.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/bool

---

In addition, it is best practice to directly specify the default value on variable creation, along with placing them on separate lines.

I'm also not sure of the use case, but using a single bool might be better than having two?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Consider revising your answer.  _"and most languages), booleans are set to False by default"_ - citation?  `c/c++` for one, variables default to _unknown_.   In my experience, it is **only** during _Debug_ builds in VS that variables are "zero'd-out".  This latter aspect can trip-up newcomers to c/c++ during Release builds.  https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/uninitialized-variables-and-undefined-behavior/

Comment: _"In addition, it is best practice to directly specify the default value on variable creation"_ - well no, in .NET the language, example c#, defines that variables _are_ initialised to their `default`. e.g. `int foo;` will be `0` at runtime in both Debug and Release builds.  You can specify say `int foo = 0;` but you will get Intellisense squiggles saying its not necessary. :)

Answer (score 1):

`bool` in `c#` defaults to `false`.

And since `Start` isn’t initialized to `true` it defaults to `false`.

When using private setter you need to set it in the constructor like so

```
    Class StartClass{
    
        StartClass()
       {
           Start = true;
       }
    public bool Start {get; private set;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the member names, it doesn't look like you don't need two variables for off/on. because you need to represent only two values on or off which can be done by using a single bool variable.

now coming to your question. you are only setting the `_turnedOn` variable. and the default value of `bool` is `false`. so `_turnedOff` will be `false` only.